# Recording lossy video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, live, vlc, recording

I'm trying to record live video stream to a file.

I tried with `VLC` using

> vlc {INPUT} --sout '#std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=file.mp4}'

I tried with `ffmpeg` using

> ffmpeg {INPUT} -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.mp4

Both records just fine, but the source tends to loose connection for 1-2seconds, and then recording just stops >.< leaving me with half finished recording :(

I want the recording to continue, and the recording app try to reconnect.

What can you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found a solution myself.

If I set VLC on loop and instruct it to append the file, it reconnects to the stream and continue recording (no black video while connection is lost tho)

the command is:

```
cvlc {INPUT} --loop --sout '#std{access=file{append},mux=ts,dst=file.mp4}'
```

Comment: how long does it continue trying to connect? even like a minute or two? does it work for rtmp too?

Answer (score 0):

What is the source, why it is losing connection?  If you can't avoid it, create some kind of 'reconnector' and use it every time connection breaks.  Then, you'll have pieces of video.  Later, glue that pieces together...

Comment: The source is RTSP:// video stream, it sometimes tend to reconnect while watching (once/twice a day)


What i'm trying to accomplish is to make a large file (whole day recording) daily.

Comment: I guess that you'll have to stick with reconnecting and appending the files later...

Comment: I can't do this because I need gapless file with a track of time - I can accomplish this by recording my display and watching the stream, but this is very dirty and CPU unfriendly, there must be another way.

Comment: It can't be another way IF the source disconnects you now and then.  You'll lose some data and there is no magic to recover it.  You CAN insert black there, for example.  Anyway, if you insist on gapless file, your main concern is how to avoid disconnections.

Comment: Black video while reconnection occurs would be perfect, Pitty the source is not managed by me, so cant avoid disconnections.

Comment: Yeah, well, then you can't insist on having it all :(